# Automate linking of requirements with test plan items

Tags: test-planning, quality-center

We are using HPQC on our project. I am new to the tool. I have an Excel sheet with the test plan ID and their related requirement IDs. The manual process is very time consuming.

How do I automate the linking of the requirement IDs with the corresponding test plan ID?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 plugins:

1. Plugin to export requirements from word document to QC
2. Plugin to export requirements from excel document to QC

Once you install these in your machine, you will get options to 'export to QC' when you open the respective application.

The pre-requisite is to have a properly formatted document (either word or excel).  It will contain your reqID and planID along with other fields.  Now, once you run the plugin it will list the available fields in your QC requirement section.  You can choose a field and map it to the respective column in your excel sheet.  Finally, click upload.

Now, the fields available in your 'requirements' section (in QC) is entirely customizable.  You may have to contact your QC Admin (or touch base with your HP point of contact) to ensure that those fields get listed when you use the plugin.

Link: http://update.external.hp.com/qualitycenter/qc100/index.html